# Deployment process on Vercel - error related to CMS

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, vercel

It's my first time deploying an app, and I selected to deploy using Vercel. It's a NextJS app and it uses Prismic CMS to get data. For some reason, in the deployment process, I'm getting an error related to the cms. The error is:

```
18:37:44.594    > Build error occurred
18:37:44.595    Error: Unexpected status code [404] on URL https://undefined.prismic.io/api/v2
18:37:44.595        at /vercel/f2f729/node_modules/prismic-javascript/cjs/prismic-javascript.js:1093:25
18:37:44.595        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
18:37:44.595      type: 'Error',
18:37:44.595      status: 404
18:37:44.595    }
18:37:44.620    error Command failed with exit code 1.
18:37:44.621    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
18:37:44.632    Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
18:37:46.595    Done with "package.json"
```

I wanted to know how to solve this, and if you guys could give me some advices and best practices related to this process, I'll be really happy.

Comment: 404 on `https://undefined.prismic.io/api/v2` suggests to me that a URL is not working. How do you build that URL? Maybe a missing env var?

Comment: I tought that it wasn't a problem, since i was able to make requests and integrate it with my app

Comment: Yes, Dominik is correct it sounds like you haven't defined your repository URL correctly. Did this work on your local machine?